# Java: A few error while implementing a multidimensional array with methods

Tags: java, for-loop, multidimensional-array

I try to make a multidimensional array with methods. But i stuck in here; my print method not working properly. It shows nothing and no errors.

```
public void bas() { // ========> print method
for (int a = 0; a < dizi.length; a++) {
    for (int b = 0; b < dizi[a].length; b++) {
        System.out.println(" dizi[" + n + "][" + m + "] = "
        + dizi[n][m]);
    }}}
```

---

it fixed.

```
public int[][] doldur() { // ========> fill method
for (int i = 0; i < dizi.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < dizi.length[i]; j++) { //problem in here: The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to int

    }
}
return dizi;
```

}

dizi.length[i] => dizi[i].length

---

rest of my code:

```
public class ikiBoyutluDizi {
int n, m;
int[][] dizi = new int[n][m];

public int[][] diziBoyutu(int a, int b) {
    return dizi;
}

public int[][] doldur() { // ========> fill method
    for (int i = 0; i < dizi.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < dizi.length[i]; j++) {

        }
    }
    return dizi;
}

public void bas() { // ========> print method
    for (int a = 0; a < dizi.length; a++) {

        for (int b = 0; b < dizi[a].length; b++) {

            System.out.println(" dizi[" + n + "][" + m + "] = "

            + dizi[n][m]);

        }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ikiBoyutluDizi dizi2x = new ikiBoyutluDizi();
    dizi2x.diziBoyutu(2, 3);
    dizi2x.doldur();
    dizi2x.bas();
}
```

}

One more thing; can you check my print method? Do you think is it working properly after fix the fill method?

Comment: Just a question. You seem to do the print method correctly (except null check) so why do you do the fill method wrong? Both nested `for` loops are of the same logic.

Comment: Btw there are semantic errors in the rest of your code (before fill method and after print method). It won't work as per how I think you're intending it to work.

Comment: @ADTC because; inattention :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the problematic line - you should use `dizi[i].length` instead of `dizi.length[i]`.

The reason is `dizi` is of type `int[][]` and thus `dizi[i]` is of type `int[]` - which is an array, but `dizi.length` is an `int`, and you actually tried to access an element in an int - which is impossible!

You might also want to make sure `dizi[i] != null` before doing so

```
public int[][] doldur() { // ========> fill method
for (int i = 0; i < dizi.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; dizi[i] != null && j < dizi[i].length; j++) { 
      //               ^                         ^
      //           not null                   dizi[i].length 
      //                                         instead of
      //                                      dizi.length[i]
      // Do domething

    }
}
```

Comment: @android93: What is the problem with it? It seems fine to me, at least from first look.

Comment: @android93: Did you make sure `n` and `m` are set to values which are not 0? You should initialize them to a different value in the c'tor or you get an array of size 0 x 0, and the loops terminates before the first iteration (since 0 < 0 yields false)

Comment: I'd say his whole program is written with a wrong understanding of the basics of OOP. There are several errors, not just the initialization error you point out. I hope he's using Eclipse to write the code.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int j = 0; j < dizi[i].length; j++)
```

dizi[i] would get the array at **i** index. and length attribute would get its length.